# How to add database content into a variable declared in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to add the content I have in my database into a variable I have declared in my view model. My goal is to display the data from my database into my "View" Page. I would like to know how I could do this, because I really want to use the Model-View-Viewmodel approach.

This is my code from my ViewModel:

```
using System.Text;
using WishListProject.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace WishListProject.ViewModels
{
  class GameListViewModel
  {
    public ObservableCollection<string> Games { get; set; }

    private ListView _listView;
    string _dbPath = 
    Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), 
    "myWishList.db3");

    public GameListViewModel()
    {
        Games = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);

        _listView = new ListView();
        _listView.ItemsSource = db.Table<Game>().OrderBy(x => x.GameNaam).ToList();

        Games.Add(????);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not declare a `ListView` in your `ViewModel`.  `ListView` is a UI element and belongs in the View.  `Games` is a ViewModel property so you can assign it in your view using data binding

```
ObservableCollection<Game> Games { get; set; }

...
var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);

Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>(db.Table<Game>().OrderBy(x => x.GameNaam).ToList());
```